# Computation of Hawking radiation without explicit Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, hawking-radiation

I've observed that computation of Hawking radiations is mostly done without explicitly computing the Hamiltonian, which would require integration over spacetime that would seem to cause problems with singularities.

Is avoiding calculation of Hamiltonian what is happening when we apply QFT to black holes?